# Moving the origin does not move the origin, but a different object instead

Tags: origin

I would like to set the origin of the selected object (with the yellow outline).

I Tab + G, then try to move the origin, but instead, it moves a different object.

Why, and how do I resolve this?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects that are moving are probably *parented* to the "origin object."

To fix this, select the objects moving with the origin, unparent the objects by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear and Keep Transformation*.

Move the origin of the parent object, then reparent the objects if needed.